# loadData tries to use data as url in webview

Tags: android, webview

```
page = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>" +
                    "</head><body>" + page + "</body></html>";
            webContent.loadData(page, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

On the call to loadData the webview gives "URL is invalid", in the onReceivedError callback 
the url is "data:text/html;charset=UTF-8;UTF-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20HTML%3E .... /body%3E%3C/html%3E". This doesn't happen on all the data I load.

Note:

- in jelly bean everything works fine, this problem occurs while testing on 2.3
- I've tried loading data with loadDataWithBaseURL but the webview does't interpret the html, just shows the string content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
webContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, page, "text/html", "UTF-8")
```

works for me, while with loadData() I get sometimes your problem

Answer (score 2):

To load url you can use the code as

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

I think below link is helpful

[webview in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but you could try to change this line:

```
webContent.loadData(page, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

to this:

```
webContent.loadData(page, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

because you already defined the charset in the call